# Google Geocode null reference exception

Tags: c#, xml, google-geocoding-api

I have made a program that takes the longitude and latitude from several properties on a london property portal.

What I am to do next is send those long+lat to geocode and return the full formatted address. The below code works for a majority of URLs that I have in my geocodeURL list, but occasionally it returns a null reference exception.

When I check the URL that failed and returned the exception manually in a browser, it works fine.

If that is the case, what am I doing wrong?

```
for (int i = 0; i < longitude.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(longitude[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(latitude[i]);
            //Console.WriteLine("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latitude[i] + "," + longitude[i] + "&sensor=false");
            geocodeURL.Add("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latitude[i] + "," + longitude[i] + "&key=0000");
        }

        foreach (string i in geocodeURL)
        {

            try
            {
                var requestUri = string.Format(i);

                var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

                var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
                var fullAddy = result.Element("formatted_address").Value;
                address.Add(fullAddy);
                Console.WriteLine(fullAddy);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }       
        }
```

The XMl response looks like this:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>street_address</type>
  <formatted_address>4 Sydenham Ave, London SE26 6UH, UK</formatted_address>
```

One such example of the exception, and you can see the URL seems to be fine, but it throws an exception regardless... (I have blacked out the key fyi)

[image]

Comment: do you know under what criteria it throws the exception? What is the value of `i`, `latitude[i]` and `longitude[i]` when it fails?

Comment: I just edited to include a screenshot. The value of i is the URL you can see (I have blacked out the key).

Comment: So in the above exception, the value of latitude was 51.442276, and longitude -0.065837

Comment: How many requests are you sending? Google have a limit on how many results you can send in a certain amount of time. It could be, depending on how many requests you are sending, that you are running up against this limit and the error is google's way of telling you to either cough up some cash or gtfo. What happens if you put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` between every few requests?

Comment: Thomas: var fullAddy = result.Element("formatted_address").Value;

User1666620: that is possible. I am sending about 300-400, so that definitely could be it. Let me try.

Comment: @JackGleeman if you are sending hundreds of requests, then I'm pretty sure that is what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, let me try the Thread.Sleep(2000). 

Do you think that should go at the beginning of the foreach every 5 times?

Comment: @JackGleeman you'll need to check the geocoding T&Cs to figure out what the limit is

Comment: alright, let me check that now. Thanks!

Comment: I'll fiddle around with the code for a bit, and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have a limit on how many results you can send in a certain amount of time. Since you are sending hundreds of requests at a time, you are probably running up against this limit and the error is google's way of telling you to either cough up some cash or gtfo.

If you don't want to pay up, you could put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` (or some other wait period) every few requests to get around the limit.

Comment: I used the http rather than https, too. Your sleep solution did the trick.